# Bing map show wrong location in Hong Kong

Tags: bing-maps

I am using Bingmap API to show location of some building. The broblem I faced is when display building in HongKong, the pushpin show wrong location.

After researching, I released that Bing map, and other online mapping services are able to publish maps in compliance with Chinese law because they conform to China’s so called GCJ-02 coordinate system, also referred to as Mars Coordinates.

> GCJ-02 is based on the familiar WGS84 coordinate system, except that
>   it is said to use an encryption algorithm to shift the coordinates by
>   a few hundred meters from their true locations. As a result, GCJ-02
>   maps appear entirely self-consistent, but the actual coordinates of
>   any given location are slightly offset from reality.

But Google map show right position in Hong Kong.So my question is there any way to fix for Bing Map API in this case?

Bing map version :

[image: Bing map version] 
Google map version :

[image: Google map version]

Answer (score 1):

Its difficult to say what the issue may be. I suspect that the address is rendering with the offset, but the base maps being displayed are not offset. If you are in china the maps will be in Chinese and offset. If using the developer API's set the market/culture to zh-CN.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I tried but it didn't worked. I am using API